# Eventlet/Gevent worker doesn't works with celery on Python3

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, gevent, eventlet

I try to work celery with gevent/eventlet on python3.

gevent/eventlet prefetch tasks from RabbitMQ broker, but never execute task.

Here's part of log which gevent/eventlet prefetch the task.

```
[2015-08-19 01:18:49,857: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.calc_test[9ceca502-d5da-43d6-84ec-f22fbd606ff0]
[2015-08-19 01:18:49,857: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x7f3705188bf8>
```

But never process that task. When I try to get with `result.get()`, that returns no params.
Is this python3 issue?
Is there any way to use gevent/eventlet worker with celery on python3?
TaskPool applied was processed, but never executed the task itself.

Comment: Does it work with process/thread workers?

Comment: I tried prefork worker and that worked.   
The worker prefetched task and executed completely.   
Is there someone have same problem?

Comment: use of gevent is uncommon - why advantage does it have for you?

Comment: I use gevent for network bound tasks.  I think using gevent for network tasks is more scalable and much faster than prefork.